# No matching client found for package name '*****.test'

Tags: android, google-play-services

Although I am following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) but my project is not building when I choose dev flavor to build my app, below you can find some details about my project and yes i have a `app/src/dev/google-services.json` and it have the `"package_name": "******.test"`

[image]

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "dummy"
        applicationIdSuffix ".test"
        
        versionCode **
        versionName "***"
    }

    prod {
        dimension "dummy"
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
       
        versionCode **
        versionName "****"
    }
}
```

this happened after i updated gradle wrapper from `gradle-5.1.1-all.zip` to `gradle-6.1.1-all.zip` and build tools from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downgraded `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'` and it worked, I think they changed something in `4.3.4` that we don't know about it yet.

Comment: I had the problem with `4.3.4`. Fixed it upgrading to `4.3.5`.

Answer (score 0):

There was something wrong with  `4.3.4` release. It seems to can't pick correct json file -> https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/163

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Adding links is great, but showing how they solve the question is much better.